# Printing dictionary keys and values on the same line, one by one in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, printing

Let's say I have a dictionary: {'Mark': 100.0, 'Peter': 50.0, 'John': 25.0}

I would like to print it like this:

```
Mark pays 100
Peter pays 50
John pays 25
```

But assuming these keys and values would be inputed in to the Program, and their amount might change, how would I do it?

Somehow with a while-loop?

The problem is I don't know how to call the keys and values in a way it would always call for the next pair once the previous pair is printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a `for` loop, you can use the `dictionary.items()` function to loop over the items of the dictionary:

```
d = {'Mark': 100.0, 'Peter': 50.0, 'John': 25.0}
for i, j in d.items():
    print (i + ' pays ' + str(j))
```

This gives the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it could be done using loop, but there is other way:

```
d = {'Mark': 100.0, 'Peter': 50.0, 'John': 25.0}
sorted_items = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda e: e[1], reverse=True)
print('\n'.join('{} pays {}'.format(k, int(v)) for k, v in sorted_items))
```

Explanation:
`d.items()` will return collection of keys and values of `d`, then I sorted these items by value and save into `sorted_items`, `'{} pays {}'.format(k, int(v))` will create string like `DictKey pays DictValue`, `'\n'.join` will merge all strings into one separated by `\n` . If you don't need to sort items by value, just skip `sorted_items = ...` step, but note, that order of elements isn't garanteed to be the same:

```
d = {'Mark': 100.0, 'Peter': 50.0, 'John': 25.0}
print('\n'.join('{} pays {}'.format(k, int(v)) for k, v in d.items()))
```

Output:

> Mark pays 100
>
> Peter pays 50
>
> John pays 25

Comment: Thanks, this response helped me a bit, although it seems to be a more advanced solution than what my current programming course requires.